# Fitting of exponential data gives me a constant function

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I conducted an experiment, where a capacitor is discharged over a (big) resistor for $t$ seconds and then the remaining charge is measured with a ballistic galvanometer. The data I have is:

```
t       phi
-----------
1.00    65
1.75    60
1.75    61
2.28    56
3.13    52
3.94    48
5.16    44
5.85    40
13.35   20
```

When I plot this data (gnuplot here) in a semilog plot, I get this:

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/10/18/latex-edit1.png

As far as I can tell, those points lie on a straight line, which would then be an exponential function. And that is what I would expect as well, since this should be

$$Q(t) = Q_0 \exp\left(\frac{-t}{RC}\right)$$

However, when I fit it using this gnuplot snippet, I get fit parameters that make no sense to me.

```
f1(x) = a * exp(-x/g);
fit f1(x) "test.dat" using 1:2:3 via a,g
```

Yields:

```
Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================

a               = 49.5555          +/- 7.647        (15.43%)
g               = -3.43204e+07     +/- 3.281e+13    (9.561e+07%)
```

I tried this same thing in Octave and Grace as well, they all give me this constant function.

How can I get a meaningful fit for this, other than trying to fit it by hand?

Comment: You could try a linear regression of ln(Q) versus t.

Comment: That worked. I am not sure why it works now …

Comment: I've never used gnuplot, but nonlinear functions are generally harder to fit than linear functions and unless you choose the starting point carefully the fit may not converge.

Comment: I'm not sure this is really on topic for us, but perhaps it could be migrated to [stats.SE] or [scicomp.SE]. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, but I can't put images in a comment.

I tried fitting your expression using the Excel Solver and got $Q_0$ = 71.1 and $1/RC$ = 0.0966. The resulting fit looked like:

[image: Solver fit]

Comment: I got $RC = 10$ with the linear fit of the logarithmic data, so that looks pretty good. I wonder how Excel can fit it, and the three tool I used failed …